# Data Grid Pro filter obscures the first two results

Tags: material-ui, mui-datatable

After filtering the DataGridPro, the filter pop-up doesn't hide. Is there a configuration/way to hide the filter menu after loading the result.

[image]

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Not easily.

The filtering is applied while the user is typing, moreover, the user could add more filters, so users must explicitly exit the filtering panel by clicking outside, or pressing <kbd>Esc</kbd>.